# How upgrade FigureCanvas programmed on pyQT4 for pyQT5

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pyqt4, pyqt5

This is a part of a code that show a figure. I was using this with pyqt4 on windows, but on linux I use anaconda, so just have pyqt5 and when I update this code dont work. Anyone knows how install pyqt4 on linux or how update this code to pyqt5?  (Python 2.7)

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

 def showfig(self):
    self.main_frame = QWidget()
    self.figure = plt.figure()
    self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
    # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init__
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, self.figure)
    self.canvas.setParent(self.main_frame)

    self.kpress = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.flip)

    self.mpress = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
    self.mrelea = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)
    self.kmove = self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)


    self.canvas.setFocusPolicy( Qt.ClickFocus )
    self.canvas.setFocus()
```

EDIT:

This is the error that appear

```
overlay loaded
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "editor.py", line 1006, in newover
      self.overset = Overset(parent=self)
   File "editor.py", line 650, in __init__
      self.showfig()
   File "editor.py", line 746, in showfig
      self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, self.figure)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: What does it mean that it does not work? You must be more specific. Also if you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: thx, add the error

Comment: Change `self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, self.figure)` to  `self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)`